# What is the difference between enable and clock in flip flops?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

I am confused between the meaning of "enable" and its function and the clocks function in terms of its form level triggered or edge triggered.

What is the meaning of level triggered vs edge triggered?

Answer (score 5):

- a clock triggered Flip-Flop (also called D-Flip-Flop) samples the input exactly at the moment when the clock signal goes up (postive or rising edge triggered) or down (negative or falling edge triggered). There are not changes of state possible during clock cycles; only at one of the edges.
- a Flip-Flop with enable input (better called transparent latch) samples the input continuously as long as enable input is active, i.e. it may change its state many times during active phase of the enable input. If enable input goes inactive the state is "frozen".

Answer (score 4):

The input signal is taken over when the enable signal is high (level) and the clock rises (edge).

So, when the enable signal is asserted after the positive clock edge, it is effectively ignored until the next clock cycle.

This is a very useful property, because the enable signal is typically generated by other logic, and is likely to change exactly after another flip-flop has taken over a new value with the last clock pulse.

Answer (score 0):

A clock (better represented as clk) is a signal which is used to make the flipflop work at its positive or negative edge (in exceptional case both edge).

But, an enable is a signal which makes the flipflop function as long as it is high (1). It can be made low (0) to make the flipflop stops its function.

Answer (score 0):

I was also confused with enable and clk. Today i did a practical and found that actually both enable and clock are control signals but the difference is that enable has low frequency than any of the inputs and clk has the highest frequency.
You can make SR flipflop with NAND gates and give the enable and clk signal to the same ckt in two cases. Observe the response , you will see that enable makes it level triggered and clk makes it edge triggered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some flip flops, particularly those that are in an FPGA, have an enable that functions like a gate on the CLK.  In this implementation the flip flop will only clock the data in when the enable is asserted, which is basically what user161986 and Simon Richter said.

Note that this is different than the enable function described above in other posts, which more typically is called a Latch Enable, or LE on the device.